# Hausdorff spaces and finite elements

Tags: classical-mechanics

Must the shape functions and the interpolation functions (which are the same in an isoparametric element) in a finite element model be elements of a Hausdorff space?   If so, is this necessary to ensure convergence to a unique solution when the mesh is refined?   If not, what are the requirements for these functions?

Comment: I think your reasoning is highly plausible. Certainly Hausdorff is necessary for uniqueness. However, I'm wondering why it arises in FEM since Hausdorff is built into $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: You'll have to give more context about how the Hausdorff space shows up in what you do for us to give an answer as to why it's needed.